# Using the read command within a while loop and running an awk script

Tags: bash, while-loop

I'm attempting to search for different file extensions and then run an awk script against each of those files however the terminal is looking for user input and I'm wondering if it's something specific to running it with the awk script as it's an interpreter? Or is it just something I'm doing wrong in my command as I'm relatively new to bash and awk

```
find ./ -type f -name '\*.txt' | while  IFS= read file; do awk -f awkScript.awk "$file" done;
```

Update ***
I was missing a semi colon but when I add this and fill in the rest of the file extensions I am looking for it give me;

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

on this command;

```
find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.gs -o -iname \*.pcf -o -iname \*.gr -o -iname \*.gsx -o -iname \*.en -o -iname \*.gst -o -iname \*.gosu -o -iname \*.descriptor -o -iname \*.txt \) -print0 | while  read -d $'\0' file do awk -f awkScript.awk "$file"; done;
```

Comment: You're missing `;` before `done`

Comment: thanks @ArkadiuszDrabczyk. This resolved the issue with the simplified command I added to the question but has created another issue with the full command. I have updated the question to include full command

Comment: Put a shebang on your code and paste it at https://shellcheck.net to validate your shell script syntax

Comment: This helped me resolve my issue. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about what you are doing? You are looking for all textfiles inside your directory. Each of those files are read, and then you treat every line inside that textfile as a file. Is this what you want?

I assume you want to do some `awk` on all textfiles, which can be done as in following example:

```
find ./ -name "*.txt" -exec awk -F. '{print $1}' {} \;
```

(find all textfiles and read the first column of those files)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Dominique. The awk script is actually using regex to parse the file contents and return data in the file if found, so I'm trying to pass the contents of each file that matches . I will be iterating over very large folders with lots of files so don't want to use exec as it will create a new shell for each file

Comment: So you are reading the entire files, giving every line to the awk script, and only then you are checking the regular expression? Why don't you use `grep` for only showing the lines you are looking for? (I believe `grep` being much faster than a scripted while-loop)

Comment: You do know that you can use `grep` as a `find` alternative? `grep -r <regular_expression> *.txt`

Comment: Hi Dominique, yeah I'm aware. The issue I have is that for each file I need to output the file name, the regex pattern, the line numbers that the regex was found on and the number of those occurrences in that file. To make things awkward the regex needs to match over multiple lines so for e.g. new \n\n\n File(). So I was using awk to only iterate over the file structure once to capture all that info.

Answer (score 1):

As for your updated command, you are still missing a semicolon before `do awk`.
BTW you could simplify your command as:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -iregex '.*\.(gs|pcf|gr|gsx|en|gst|gosu|descriptor|txt)$' -print0 | xargs -0 awk -f awkScript.awk
```